# BIRT html format report columns width getting shrink while add many columns

Tags: birt

I'm using BIRT version 4_5_0. In html format report the result is displayed in A4 size only. I unable to resize the resultant. If I choose more columns then the columns width getting shrink. But I want that columns width would not get shrink if I add any number of columns and also width should be followed by what size I fixed in API. If we add more columns then horizontal scroll bar will be placed usually. But It's not an issue for me. Is any settings/API available to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Birt output format By default fixed Layout.

You can Change the layout fixed to **auto**.

automatically horizontal scroll bar will come. Your problem may will solve

```
        ReportDesignHandle designHandle = session.createDesign();
        designHandle.setLayoutPreference(DesignChoiceConstants.REPORT_LAYOUT_PREFERENCE_AUTO_LAYOUT);
```